# Is there any smart implementation of flatMap that is able to infer common type characteristics for its input and output?

Tags: scala

Consider the following type:

`case class Subscriber(books: List[String])`

And its instance wrapped in an option:

`val s = Option(Subscriber(List("one", "two", "three")))`

And an attempt to println all books for a subscriber:

`s.flatMap(_.books).foreach(println(_))`

This fails, due to:

`Error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[String]
 required: Option[?]
      result.flatMap(_.books).foreach(println(_))
                       ^`

This is kind of expected, because `flatMap` must return types compatible to its source object and one can easily avoid this error by doing:

`s.toList.flatMap(_.books).foreach(println(_))`

I could also avoid flatMap, but its not the point.

But isn't there some smart method of achieving this without explicit `toList` conversion? Intuitively, `None` and `List.empty` have a lot in common. And during compilation of `s.flatMap`, `s` is implicitly converted to `Traversable`.

Something in scalaz, maybe?

Comment: "I could also avoid flatMap, but its not the point" -- then what is the point? The defining behavior of flatMap is that for some context M[A], it takes a function from A => M[B] and returns M[B]. In this case, M is a List, B is a String, A is a Subscriber. If you want something that given the context Option[Subscriber], takes a function from Subscriber => List[String], and returns a List[String], then by definition you don't want flatMap.

Comment: Well, the point is that 'List.empty' and `None` share common attributes, but in case of `flatMap` scala compiler fails to identify them. Doing a bit of research, I've found http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Natural-Transformation.html

Comment: I actually think such an implementation of flatMap would be pretty stupid. flatMap is supposed to return the same type for the container.

Answer (score 0):

I think **smart implementation of flatamap** is a bit missleading.
Such an implementation, as flatmap is well defined, would break the **monadic** behavior one expects when using **flatmap** and be in fact **broken**.

The problem with the *smart method* is

- How should the compiler know what kind of type to use.
- How should it be possible to infer if you wanted a **List[_]** or and **Option[_]** as a result?
- What to do with other types, unknown types and what kind of conversion to apply on them ?

You could achieve the same result you would with the .list in that way , because for given example types don't matter (except you are aiming for a list of Units) at all as there is just output as a side effect:

```
s foreach ( _.books foreach println )
```

A direction to go, might be an implicit conversion using **structural types** but you would get a performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

The smarter way to do that would be is by using map.

```
val s = Option(Subscriber(List("one", "two", "three")))
s.map(_.books.map(println))
```

foreach has side effects while map doesn't